# file upload is not successful ,why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, yaml

I'm going crazy to upload a file into my ruby 3.2.8 application. I need your help! I tried this code:

[Why yaml file upload does not work? I think permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286583/why-yaml-file-upload-does-not-work-i-think-permission-problems)

but it does not work, does not create the file in "public", but only creates the temporary file. Today I found a new way:

[Rails 3 - upload files to public directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776252/rails-3-upload-files-to-public-directory)

So, View:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>

<%= form_for :uploadFile, :url => "/upload/uploadfile", :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <label for="uploadFile">Select File:</label>
  <%= f.file_field :upload %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload", :disable_with => 'Uploading...' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def uploadFile
    require 'fileutils'
    tmp = params[:uploadFile][:upload].tempfile
    file = File.join("public", params[:uploadFile][:upload].original_filename)
    FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file
    flash.now[:notice]="File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

but same problem. in "public" there is no file :(

Logs says:

```
Started POST "/upload/uploadfile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-12 11:19:04 +0100
Processing by UploadController#uploadfile as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"WI23X2HeanJpQJoRFc8NUJ078yLYpKgRE3VnJDBeccA=", "uploadFile"=>{"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x47e4238 @original_filename="newCases.yml", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadFile[upload]\"; filename=\"newCases.yml\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/Simo/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20121112-4716-1geiytj>>}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
  [1m[36mSetting Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered upload/uploadfile.html.erb within layouts/upload (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

ahh, the upload file is yaml, change anything?

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "comma", "~> 3.0.3"
gem 'fastercsv', '1.5.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding :url to form_for like

```
form_for :uploadFile, :url => "/upload/uploadfile"
```

will help?
With rails 3.2.8 your uploading works fine, except I added :url parameter.

Comment: I also have rails 3.2.8 and I have added your tip, but ... nothing.
can be a problem not due to code but to something else? permits or other .. you have set something in your application?

Comment: no, totally new app. Maybe the problem is caused by Content-Type: application/octet-stream ?

Comment: I do not know even know what to say, how do I change it?

Comment: Can you provide your Gemfile (post it to pastebin.com, for example)?And do you have write permissions on public folder?

Comment: I did not write permissions for any folder, how?

Comment: I have windows 7 and I do: config / properties / attributes / I remove the check on read-only and I give ok. but if I retrace the way, it is still on read only. I had to do this? Why it does not change?

Comment: I have set "full control" on the ruby application folder, so in addition to have read and execute permissions, I also edit and write permissions, but nothing changes. I'm going crazy !

Comment: Might  I suggest using the gem 'paperclip' for uploading files to a ruby app. Takes about 5 mins to setup

Comment: I also wanted to install paperclip but then I thought that if my code works in Shamir K. , Is not a code problem, then both with my than with that of paperclip, some setting missing does not run the loading. or I'm wrong?

Comment: Tried this code under win7 - works fine. Have no idea what causes problem :( Maybe you will post your code to github?

Comment: my application is only locally: (